# Disable Visual Studio code formatting programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Can Visual Studio code auto formatting be disabled programmatically?

I want my to keep related properties together in a class like

```
public class Test
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public bool Prop2 { get; set; }
    internal string Prop2String { get { return Prop2 ? "Yes" : "No"; } }
}
```

but Visual Studio formats it to

```
public class Test
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public bool Prop2 { get; set; }

    internal string Prop2String
    {
        get { return Prop2 ? "Yes" : "No"; }
    }
}
```

I don't want to turn off formatting altogether on Visual Studio but only in specific places in the code.

Comment: You can get the first "option" by not hitting return as you type...? (note: it does still format the spacing *on that line* as you close braces)

Comment: I'm jealous. My visual studio doesn't format like the second one. Why would you not want it like that.

Comment: I've got a class with loads of properties and some of these internal properties are only translating the other properties using extension methods. Like bool to 'Yes'/'No' strings for storing in a poorly designed database.

Comment: While it may be possible (there is extensive API to control VS), I'd recommend checking if you can adjust existing formatting options to your liking or maybe obtain R# and use its formatting (as it have even more options).

Comment: You can get the first "option" by not hitting return as you type...? (note: it does still format the spacing on that line as you close braces) - Hitting return doesn't format the code anyway. What's the point if it all can get wiped out when others replace the closing brace of the class / reformat the code?

Comment: @VJ... When I'm editing, I never get the second option unless I add a newline manually. I can type the first option as-is just fine. The only changes Vs makes is adding interior spaces when I add the final `}`. If someone else is adding a new-line, *tell them to stop*.

Answer (score 0):

Your unable to disable certain fragments, you can type it how you want.  However, if you accidentally hit `CTRL + K then F` it will automatically invoke styling for the given area.  You either have it **all** on or **all** off.

You can find the specifics here:

- Tools
- Options
- Text Editor

Then simply choose your language and modify formatting to your desire.  Basically as I mentioned it is riddled with check boxes or radio buttons.  *(On or Off)*

Though you don't like choice two, it is a bit more legible in my opinion.  Especially once Visual Studio adds their reference and other data above methods / properties.

---

**Example:**

If you type:

```
public string Name{get;set;}
```

Visual Studio will change it to this:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

If you type it like this:

```
public string Name
{
     get;
     set;
}
```

Visual Studio will not change it, if you type code as a bracketed one liner Visual Studio usually will keep it like so.  So when you attempt Visual Studio to force the style to change:

```
internal string Prop2String { get { return Prop2 ? "Yes" : "No"; } }
```

It keeps it exactly how it is written.

Comment: Please don't use keyboard shortcuts alone in recommendations - everyone keyboard setup is different and it is hard to see which one you mean. I.e. for me Ctrl+Shift+F is "Find in Files" which clearly does not do any formatting (VS 2005 C# + R# scheme).

Comment: *Your unable to disable certain fragments, you can type it how you want.* - Could you rephrase that? I am not sure what it means.. I believe the word "accidently" is redundant - it will automatically invoke styling even if it's done purposely. Could you add details of what settings needs to be changed for the specific issue that the OP has? You are basically saying "there are settings in Visual Studio that you can change". It being "riddled with check boxes" doesn't help much either..